# Loading data from a UTF-16 Le (.txt) file to Azure SQL Db

Tags: csv, azure-sql-database, export-to-csv

We have a `.txt` file with encoding `UTF-16 LE` (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36550038/1232087), as well). We need to load this file into an `Azure SQL database`. We are first trying to convert this file to a `csv` format by using [Text Import Wizard of Data Excel 365](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-import-wizard-c5b02af6-fda1-4440-899f-f78bafe41857) wizard. But if we use the `^|^,^|^` as a custom delimiter, the first and last columns still end up with `^|^` value.

**Question**: What may be possible solutions/work arounds for converting this type of file to `csv`?

**Remarks**: This is a huge file (1GB) with about 150 columns. Following is just a sample for explaining the scenario in this post.

**Sample of the txt file**:

```
^|^Col0^|^,^|^Col1^|^,^|^Col2^|^,^|^Col3^|^,^|^Col4^|^,^|^Col5^|^,^|^Col6^|^,^|^Col7^|^
^|^1234^|^,^|^4600869848^|^,^|^6000.00^|^,^|^2021-12-20 10:16:19.3600000^|^,^|^False^|^,^|^^|^,^|^^|^,^|^2^|^
^|^5431^|^,^|^3425143451^|^,^|^30000.00^|^,^|^2021-12-13 10:27:44.9030000^|^,^|^False^|^,^|^^|^,^|^^|^,^|^2^|^
.....................
............................
```

**After using the delimiter** `^|^,^|^` **in Excel text import wizard**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mentioning the **^|^,^|^** as custom delimiter, you can mention comma as a delimiter, that will give you a result like below:

[image]

Then you can record a macro to replace the desired characters which is **^|^** after importing is done as mentioned in below link:

[Create A Macro Code To Achieve Find And Replace Text In Excel](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5239-excel-find-and-replace-macro-code.html)