# Why does endianness not reverse for unpack on a 'char[]' buffer when I switch signs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pack

I've performed the following in the Python 3.7.0 interpreter:

```
>>> test = pack('<8s', b'\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03')
>>> test
b'\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03'
>>> type(test)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> unpack('>8s', test)
(b'\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03',)
>>> unpack('<8s', test)
(b'\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03',)
```

Expected behavior: When I run unpack with **big endian** specified, the unpack returns the bytes in the reverse order from the original input which is packed with **little endian.**

Actual behavior: The bytes never change order at all.

Comment: Endianness won't make any difference to a string of bytes. Try it with some integers or floats.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it true that endianness only affects the memory layout of numbers,but not string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804824/is-it-true-that-endianness-only-affects-the-memory-layout-of-numbers-but-not-str)